# Grep lines with a maximum number of characters

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, grep

How can I improve the following command:

```
grep 'sting' filename
```

such that to print only the lines with a maximum number of characters? For example only the lines which contain less than 100 characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
grep -E '^.{1,100}$' filename | grep 'string'
```

OR using a **single awk command** like this:

```
awk '/string/ && length() <= 100' filename
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me `egrep '.{1,100}' filename` doesn't give the expected result. For example `egrep '.{1,100}' filename` give me the same output as `cat filename`. `egrep` version: 2.14, bash version: 4.2.45(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

Comment: You need to anchor the regex, as any line with more than 100 characters will have a substring of length 100. Use `^.{1,100}$`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the another version in `awk`:

```
awk '$0 ~ /string/ { if(length($0) <= 100) print}'
```

Comment: This can be shorten to `awk '/string/ && length($0)<=100'` same as anubhava posted :)

Answer (score 0):

With sed for lines between >=10 and <=90 characters:

```
sed -i -r '/^.{10,90}$/!d' $file;
```